# Convert a frozenset to a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, frozenset

I have the following *frozenset*:

```
f_set = [frozenset({8, 14, 15, 18}), frozenset({1, 2, 3, 7, 8}), frozenset({0, 4, 5})]
```

I need to convert `f_set` into a dictionary as the following

- For the first set, I need the dictionary to have a value of 0.
- For the second set, I need the dictionary to have a value of 1.
- For the third set, I need the dictionary to have a value of 2.

Now, in case some keys are existed in multiple set, assign a new values to them. In this case 8 existed in both set 1 and set 2, so assign a value of 3.

> dict1 = {8:3, 14:0, 15:0, 18:0, 1:1, 2:1, 3:1, 7:1, 0:2, 4:2, 5:2}

Note: my actual `f_set`  contains more than three sets, so I'd like to avoid doing that manually.

Comment: What if the sets have duplicated value (i.e. duplicated key in resulting dict)?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. In this case, we can repeat this item, say, twice, and each has its own value.

Comment: `dict` can't have duplicated keys.

Comment: So how this case can be handled?

Comment: ok-- in this case assign a new value to it-- I'm going to edit the question. Thanks!

Comment: for "8: 1" it has a value of 1... can we assign a differed value (that's not already assigned), say 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use dict comprehension with `enumerate`:

```py
f_set = [frozenset({8, 14, 15, 18}), frozenset({1, 2, 3, 7, 8}), frozenset({0, 4, 5})]

dict1 = {x: i for i, s in enumerate(f_set) for x in s}
print(dict1)
# {8: 1, 18: 0, 14: 0, 15: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 7: 1, 0: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2}
```

Note that, if the sets are not mutually disjoint, some keys will be discarded, since a dict cannot have duplicate keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply loop over the frozensets to set each of them in an output dictionary:

```py
output = dict()
    
for i in range(len(f_set)):
    for s in f_set[i]:
        output[s] = i
```

Note although the order may be different from what you have, order shouldn't matter in the dictionary.